# Elasticsearch match query: same string but score is not equal to 1

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl, scoring

Let's say that I have this match query in elasticsearch:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": 
            "query": {
                "match" : {
                    "stringQuery" : "blood patient"
                }
            },
            "max_boost": 1,
            "min_score" : 0

        }
    }
}
```

I have to mention that I want the scores to be between 0 and 1.

My problem is that when the "stringQuery" variable has the same value as the search term (in this occasion "blood patient") the score is not equal to 1, despite the fact that the string is the same.

Can anyone explain why this happens? And how can I demand from Elasticsearch to give me _score = 1 when the search term is the same as the variable?

Comment: check constant_score documentation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

Comment: thanks but it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Do I get it right that you want the score to be 1 if there is exact match, from 0 to 1 if there is some match (different order, some terms missing, etc) and score to be 0 if there is no match? Maybe you could please add few more examples with actual vs expected scores?

Comment: yes Nikolay! this is exactly what I am looking for!